# Dynamically build an object from a strongly typed class using C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

Currently, am adding the properties and values to the object manually like this **example** and sending to Dapper.SimpleCRUD to fetch data from Dapper Orm. This is the **desired output** I would like to achieve.

```
object whereCriteria = null;
whereCriteria = new
{
    CountryId = 2,
    CountryName = "Anywhere on Earth",
    CountryCode = "AOE",
    IsActive = true
};
```

The following class should build the object in the above mentioned format and return the ready-made object.

```
public static class WhereClauseBuilder
{
    public static object BuildWhereClause(object model)
    {
        object whereObject = null;
        var properties = GetProperties(model);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var value = GetValue(property, model);

            //Want to whereObject according to the property and value. Need help in this part!!!
        }

        return whereObject;
    }

    private static object GetValue(PropertyInfo property, object model)
    {
        return property.GetValue(model);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetProperties(object model)
    {
        return model.GetType().GetProperties();
    }
}
```

This function `WhereClauseBuilder.BuildWhereClause(object model)` should return the object in **expected format (mentiond above)**. Here is the implementation of how I would like to use.

```
public sealed class CountryModel
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class WhereClauseClass
{
    public WhereClauseClass()
    {
        var model = new CountryModel()
        {
            CountryCode = "AOE",
            CountryId = 2,
            CountryName = "Anywhere on Earth",
            IsActive = true
        };

        //Currently, won't return the correct object because the implementation is missing.
        var whereClauseObject = WhereClauseBuilder.BuildWhereClause(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: This link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(VS.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(VS.71).aspx) will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that link. But, am curious to know how to construction the object which can be returned in a desired format?

Comment: I don't get exactly what you're trying to do. You can create an instance of an [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) and use it with dynamic but I'm not sure that this is what you want. The other way is to create a code template that contains all needed namespaces and a class body and fill in the property definitions. Having this you can compile the code at runtime and create an instance of your object. Microsoft.CSharp will help you in that case.

Comment: I have already looked into ExpandoObject but again I don't know how to create the object with the desired output I want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

```
private const string CodeTemplate = @"
    namespace XXXX
    {
        public class Surrogate
        {
    ##code##
        }
    }";

public static Type CreateSurrogate(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties)
{
    var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    var compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters { GenerateInMemory = true };
    foreach (var item in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(x => !x.IsDynamic))
    {
        compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(item.Location);
    }

    var propertiesCode = 
        string.join("\n\n", from pi in properties
                            select "public " + pi.PropertyType.Name + " " + pi.Name + " { get; set; }");

    var source = CodeTemplate.Replace("##code##", propertiesCode);

    var compilerResult = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameters, source);
    if (compilerResult.Errors.HasErrors)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Surrogate compilation error: {0}", string.Join("\n", compilerResult.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>())));
    }

    return compilerResult.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes().First(x => x.Name == "Surrogate");
}
```

And now use it:

```
public static object BuildWhereClause(object model)
{
    var properties = GetProperties(model);
    var surrogateType = CreateSurrogate(properties);
    var result = Activator.CreateInstance(surrogateType);

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var value = GetValue(property, model);
        var targetProperty = surrogateType.GetProperty(property.Name);
        targetProperty.SetValue(result, value, null);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I didn't compile that. It's only written here. Maybe there are some errors. :-)

EDIT:

To use ExpandoObject you can try this:

```
public static object BuildWhereClause(object model)
{
    var properties = GetProperties(model);
    var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)new ExpandoObject();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var value = GetValue(property, model);
        result.Add(property.Name, value);
    }

    return result;
}
```

But I don't know whether this will work for you.

Comment: I was going to suggest the `ExpandoObject` and casting it to the dictionary but i see you've already added it to your update.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I have trouble converting `ExpandoObject` to the desired output I want. Maybe, there is a way and I don't know?

Comment: @CoderAbsolute What output type do you need? You will also have problems to convert the dynamically created surrogate.

Comment: I haven't tried the Surrogate, it looks a bit complex am still studying the code. But the **desired output** is mentioned in the first section of my question.

Comment: Please give me a moment, if the question is confusing then I will rephrase it. My head is spinning.. :P

Comment: @CoderAbsolute You can't create an anonymous class at runtime. Also: anonymous classes can't be converted into other types. BTW: I think that anonymous classes are only syntactic sugar and the compiler will create a named type. That's exactly what my code to create a surrogate does. Maybe it's better to use [Reflection.Emit](http://www.drdobbs.com/generating-code-at-run-time-with-reflect/184416570) to create the dynamic class. My class above need to know the type names as written in code instead of using the type object. There are a lot of maybe's and tink's - hopefully that helps.

Comment: Noted Vera. I will revise my thoughts and maybe I have taken the most difficult path.