# Neat approach to Cast Strongly Type to Anonymous Type in C#

Tags: c#, dapper, anonymous-types, strong-typing

Follow up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522562/dynamically-build-an-object-from-a-strongly-typed-class-using-c) question.

I would like to cast from `Strongly Typed` to `Anonymous Type` Result. For an example the following class should be converted to Anonymous Type Object during run time. Am struggling to achieve this.

```
public sealed class CountryModel
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

*Usage*:

```
new CountryModel()
{
    CountryCode = "AOE",
    CountryId = 2,
    CountryName = "Anywhere on Earth",
    IsActive = true
};
```

**Anonymous type:**

The above Strongly typed should be converted to Anonymous and the end result would look like this (*captured via Immediate Window)*:

```
{ CountryId = 2, CountryName = "Anywhere on Earth", CountryCode = "AOE", IsActive = true }
    CountryCode: "AOE"
    CountryId: 2
    CountryName: "Anywhere on Earth"
    IsActive: true
```

*Note: I need this casting to be done so that I can pass the object to Dapper.SimpleCRUD and Dapper ORM Library.*

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It isn't an anonymous object, it can be boxed to an `object`. But it isn't anonymous

Comment: Added a note to my question. But, here you go again " need this casting to be done so that I can pass the object to Dapper.SimpleCRUD and Dapper ORM Library"

Comment: Dapper takes `dynamic` or `object` so like I said, it can be boxed to `object` so this will work `object value = new CountryModel();`

Comment: What problem are you seeing currently? Dapper is perfectly happy if you just pass it your object - it doesn't care whether things are "anonymous" or not. I can't speak for SimpleCRUD, note.

Comment: @CallumLinington that's not actually "boxed" - since it is already a reference type; it is just passing a class instance as an object reference; but yes, dapper is perfectly happy with that

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks for the reply! Dapper is working perfectly alright with the strongly typed but I think I have a problem with SimpleCRUD. I will look into it otherwise I will write my own wrapper around Dapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var obj = new {
   CountryCode = item.CountryCode,
   CountryId = item.CountryId,
   CountryName = item.CountryName,
   IsActive = item.IsActive
   };
```

Comment: No idea why this <strike>is</strike> *was* downvoted; it does *literally* what is requested (although you can actually make it terser - just `new { item.CountryCode, item.CountryId, ...}` is fine - it infers the names). The question in my mind, though, is whether it is *useful or necessary* to do this - that is really a question for the OP, though

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. This answer hasn't been downvoted at all.